# Microsoft azure IoT Hub: Decode a message from base64 format to 8-utf in message route query

Tags: json, azure, utf-8, base64, azure-iot-hub

I have a device which sends sensor data to an IoT-hub. The messages that I get from the device are with base64 format encoded. I cannot change it in my device's settings. Thus, when I open the JSON data, the "body" values are encoded (cannot be read) and must be converted to the UTF-8 format. I would like to know whether it is possible to write a code in "message route query" in IoT Hub so that Microsoft azure automatically converts the received JSON data in format UTF-8 to see the values of the signals?

Thanks in advance

Br
Masoud

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Sending the message as ***UTF-8*** encoded ***JSON*** is setting two steps on your message object. Adding the following code to my application will solve the problem. You can refer this ***GitHub*** [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/main/azure-iot-device/samples/async-hub-scenarios/send_message.py) .

```
msg.content_encoding = "utf-8"
msg.content_type = "application/json"
```

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#routing-endpoints

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that there is no place to add these codes to my message object! My device is a data acquisition system which sends signal values automatically in JSON format to iot Hub in Azure. When I add these codes in message routing query in IoT Hub, I receive an error, that the code is wrong.